# How to handle timezones in Rails when using fixed time ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone, activesupport

I feel like I'm going round the houses on this one.

In summary, I have a Location model which has opening hours, modelled as `opens_at` and `closes_at` in the DB.

All times are stored as UTC in the database.

If I create a location in New York with `opens_at` set at 08:30 in my form and it gets saved to the DB as 08:30 UTC, why would I need to worry about timezones? I don't want to display the time in local time because the user would then see opening hours of 03:30.

Am I overthinking this? Do I only need to worry about timezones if I have users in multiple countries attending the same event at the same time?

As this is about physical locations, it feels to me that it wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create a location in New York with `opens_at` set at 08:30 in my form and it gets saved to the DB as 08:30 UTC, why would I need to worry about timezones?

Because 08:30 in New York is *not* 08:30 UTC.  It's not even the same time for all dates.

- It's 13:30 UTC when New York is observing Eastern Standard Time (EST, UTC-5)
- It's 12:30 UTC when New York is observing Eastern Daylight Time (EDT, UTC-4)

So, if the location opens at the same time every day, then you *must* store it in local time.  Otherwise you'll be off by an hour one way or the other following the next DST transition.

This can be an issue even for time zones that don't use DST, and even for non-recurring events, because the various governments of the world control the time zones within their borders.  They can change whether to start observing DST or stop observing it, the dates and times that DST transitions occur, or their standard offset from UTC.  Some give adequate notice when they make such changes, and others do not.  There's always some non-zero chance that a given time zone might *change* its behavior between when you initially recorded the event and when the event takes place.  If you recorded using local time, all you need to do is update the time zone data on your systems (which often happens automatically).  However, if you recorded the event using UTC then you could be off when converting *back* after such a change.

In general, *future* events should always be stored in terms that the event is described - which is almost always in *local* time of some particular time zone.  Store the [IANA time zone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (e.g., `"America/New_York"`) with the location or event so that you can convert when you need to, but converting to UTC prematurely can lead to losing sight of the original information.

Save the "Always UTC" mindset for *past* or *present* events, such as timestamping a transaction.

Comment: Thanks - this has helped me move along in the right direction and I have some semblance of it working now. The product is slightly complicated by the fact that the timezone applies to the location of the space and the user of the space. They might be but are not guaranteed to be the same. So I need the booking record at the location time but when making the booking it will be helpful to display in the user's time also.

Comment: Indeed.  Often the time zone of the user is not the same as the time zone of the location or event.  Of course it depends on scenario. For example, say the event was a restaurant reservation.  The user's current time zone wouldn't matter because the expectation would be that the user would physically go to the restaurant at the time of the reservation.  Thus, only the restaurant's time zone matters.  Other scenarios are different, such as online webinars where the time of the event should be adjusted to the time zone of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I actually have run into this. If the user is only going to see the time in the local time zone, then it is not really necessary to save in UTC with time zone. You can save it in local time without time zone.

Reference: [Postgres Time without Time Zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

Some developers will say that you should save it in UTC with the time zone, but I can see two arguments against it:

1. If you don't need it now and you may never need it.
2. You may not have access to the Time Zone now or may need extra code/complexity to implement and validate.
3. You can probably add it later if you know the time zone or lat/lon or address.